# Duplication/ Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about a rule in my textbook related to differential equations.

If we are considering a differential equation of the form $y"+ay'+b= f(x)$ such that $f(x)=P(x)e^{rx}\cos kx$ with $\deg(P)\leq m$, it is written that in order to determine the particular solution, I should set $y(x)=x^s[(A_0+A_1 x+...+A_mx^m)e^{rx}\cos kx+(B_0+B_1 x+...+B_mx^m)e^{rx}\sin kx]$ where s is the smallest nonnegative integer such that such no term in the particular solution duplicates a term in the general solution.

Could someone explain to me what do they mean by "duplicate" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, you find guess the whole solution as you noted above. This solution contains a part $y_c$ which is related to homogenous associated equation, and another part which contains $y_p$ the particular solution. What we should care about it is to distinguish these two parts because they all be independent with each other. And that's why the method suggest you to do that. In these kinds of equation, I personally prefer to apply [The Annihilator method**] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_method).

Comment: So for instance, if the solution of the homogenous equation is of the form $e^{r_0}(A\cos x+ B\sin x)$, I can't have a particular solution of the form $e^{r_0}(A\cos x+ B\sin x)$. Therefore, we multiply by x ie $e^{r_0}(Ax\cos x+ Bx\sin x)$ right ?

Comment: @user43758: Most of time yes, but we may change the case if the ODE changes.

Comment: The "annihilator" method: yikes...sounds "scary" :-)

Answer (score 1):

"duplicates" = "coincides with".

Stated in simpler words: you should not use the terms that satisfy the homogeneous equation, since they will not contribute anything to the right-hand side, and therefore will not help you get $f(x)$ on the right.

On the same page, Boyce & DiPrima give a semi-helpful suggestion about what $s$ should be. In practice, what you do is (i) solve the homogeneous equation first; (ii) compare your solution with $f$. If $f$, or one of its summands, coincides with your solution, you will need an extra power of $x$ in your candidate for particular solution.

Comment: So for instance, if the solution of the homogenous equation is of the form $e^{r_0}(A\cos x+ B\sin x)$, I can't have a particular solution of the form $e^{r_0}(A\cos x+ B\sin x)$. Therefore, we multiply by x ie $e^{r_0}(Ax\cos x+ Bx\sin x)$ right ?

Comment: @user43758 Correct.